# opencvでマウスイベントを使って円で線を描こうとすると応答なしと出てしまう

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda

こちら初心者であまり詳しくありませんが、opencvのマウスイベントを使って円を連続で描き続け線を描けるようにしたいと思っていたのですが、実行すると応答なしと表示されてしまいます。
マウスの左クリックを押している最中のみ円を描き、離すと終わるようにしたいと思っていたのですが、そこの文をいじっていると応答なしになってしまい、解決策がわかりません。解決策の回答お願いします。

コードはこんな感じです。

```
img = cv2.imread("image01.jpg")

cv2.namedWindow("image")

R = 0
G = 0
B = 0

cv2.createTrackbar("R", "image", R, 255, printing)
cv2.createTrackbar("G", "image", G, 255, printing)
cv2.createTrackbar("B", "image", B, 255, printing)

def draw_circle(event, x, y, flags, param):
    print (event)
    if event == 1:
        while event <= 1:
            cv2.circle(img,(x,y),7,(B,G,R), thickness=-1)
            if event == 4:
                break

cv2.setMouseCallback("image", draw_circle)  

while True:
    R = cv2.getTrackbarPos("R", "image")
    G = cv2.getTrackbarPos("G", "image")
    B = cv2.getTrackbarPos("B", "image")

    cv2.imshow('image', img)

    if cv2.waitKey(10) == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: こんな記事が参考になりそうです。[Draw On Images Using Mouse In OpenCV Python](https://mlhive.com/2022/04/draw-on-images-using-mouse-in-opencv-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`draw_circle`関数の中で無限ループが発生しています。
下記のようにマウスボタンの押下状態をフラグで管理することで解決できます。

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("image01.jpg")

cv2.namedWindow("image")

R = 0
G = 0
B = 0

cv2.createTrackbar("R", "image", R, 255, lambda x: None)
cv2.createTrackbar("G", "image", G, 255, lambda x: None)
cv2.createTrackbar("B", "image", B, 255, lambda x: None)

drawing = False  # マウスの左ボタンが押されているかどうかのフラグ

def draw_circle(event, x, y, flags, param):
    global drawing, img, B, G, R

    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        drawing = True
    elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        drawing = False

    if drawing:
        cv2.circle(img, (x, y), 7, (B, G, R), thickness=-1)

cv2.setMouseCallback("image", draw_circle)

while cv2.getWindowProperty("image", cv2.WND_PROP_VISIBLE) > 0:
    R = cv2.getTrackbarPos("R", "image")
    G = cv2.getTrackbarPos("G", "image")
    B = cv2.getTrackbarPos("B", "image")

    cv2.imshow('image', img)

    if cv2.waitKey(10) == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: 非常に分かりやすかったです！本当に助かりました、ありがとうございます！！